# Cancel child coroutine when parent completes

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Given this code:

```
runBlocking {
  val job = launch { while(true) delay(10.milliseconds) }
  // other work
  job.cancelAndJoin()
}
```

is it possible to auto-cancel `job` without explicitly doing so at the end of `runBlocking`? Perhaps start it in such a way that Kotlin knows it's just monitoring something in the background of the main coroutine?

Comment: You mean just so you won't have to store the job variable and remember to cancel it at the bottom, keeping the behavior contained to one spot?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Exactly. In production code, the `launch` could be several suspended method calls deep inside.

Comment: can you replace launch with flow or with some observable? it hard to say, need more information